# Side by side char matrix in a fashion way

Tags: c

I'm trying to make C code similar to the famous `bigdigits.py`.

To achieve this result I've already tried concatenated `for` loops.

This generated the closest result I could find

```
scanf("%s", nums);

system("cls");

printf("\n");

x = strlen(nums);

for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    if(nums[i] == '1'){
        printf("%s",n[1].number);
    }else if(nums[i] == '2'){
        printf("%s",n[2].number);
    }else if(nums[i] == '3'){
        printf("%s",n[3].number);
    }else if(nums[i] == '4'){
        printf("%s",n[4].number);
    }else if(nums[i] == '5'){
        printf("%s",n[5].number);
    }else if(nums[i] == '6'){
        printf("%s",n[6].number);
    }else if(nums[i] == '7'){
        printf("%s",n[7].number);
    }else if(nums[i] == '8'){
        printf("%s",n[8].number);
    }else if(nums[i] == '9'){
        printf("%s",n[9].number);
    }else if(nums[i] == '0'){
        printf("%s",n[0].number);
        }
}
```

This is what I tried to find the wanted result (the `for` loops mentioned before)

Ps.: Failed miserably

```
scanf("%s", nums);

x = strlen(nums);

for(int k = 0; k < x; k++){
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
           if(nums[k] == '1'){
                printf("%s", n[i][j]);
           }if(nums[k] == '2'){
                printf("%s", n2[i][j]);
           }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The input is something like "12" and the output(the one that I want to achieve) is something like

```
 *     ***
**    *   *
 *       *
 *      *
 *    *
 *    *
***   *****
```

But at the moment my output looks like this

```
 *     
**    
 *    
 *    
 * 
 * 
***

 ***
*   *
   *
  *
*
*
*****
```

Comment: Consider using `printf("%s",n[nums[i]-'0'].number);` instead of the ten `if` and `else`.

Comment: Step 1: Re-order `for(int k = 0; k < x; k++){
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){` loops to achieve goal.

Comment: @chux, how should i do that?

Comment: @Osiris, very nice upgrade, ty

Answer (score 2):

Let's backtrack a bit, and look at the general logic before we write the code.

You obviously have an array of big digits, something like

```
#define  DIGITS  10
#define  ROWS    5

const char *const bigdigit[ROWS][DIGITS] = {
    { " 0 ", " 1 ", "22 ", "33 ", "  4", "555", " 66", "777", " 8 ", " 9 " },
    { "0 0", " 1 ", "  2", "  3", " 44", "5  ", "6  ", "  7", "8 8", "9 9" },
    { "0 0", " 1 ", " 2 ", " 3 ", "444", "55 ", "66 ", " 7 ", " 8 ", " 99" },
    { "0 0", " 1 ", "2  ", "  3", "  4", "  5", "6 6", " 7 ", "8 8", "  9" },
    { " 0 ", " 1 ", "222", "33 ", "  4", "55 ", " 6 ", " 7 ", " 8 ", "99 " }
};
```

so that `bigdigit[row][digit]` describes row `row` (0..4) of digit `digit` (0..9).  Above, each digit is 3 characters wide, but it does not matter, as long as the rows for any specific character all have the same width (i.e., the `"` align!).

Let's say you wish to print `251` using those big digits.

Because `printf()` outputs from top to bottom, left to right, we need to print the top row of `2` first, then the top row of `5` next, then top row of `1`, and finally a new line, until we print the rest of the rows.

So, the loop must obviously be

```
/* char *message;                    or 
   char  message[MAXSIZE];           contains the digits to be printed
   int   columns = strlen(message);  is the number of digits */

for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {

    for (column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
        switch (message[column]) {
            case '0': fputs(bigdigit[row][0], stdout); break;
            case '1': fputs(bigdigit[row][1], stdout); break;
            case '2': fputs(bigdigit[row][2], stdout); break;
            case '3': fputs(bigdigit[row][3], stdout); break;
            case '4': fputs(bigdigit[row][4], stdout); break;
            case '5': fputs(bigdigit[row][5], stdout); break;
            case '6': fputs(bigdigit[row][6], stdout); break;
            case '7': fputs(bigdigit[row][7], stdout); break;
            case '8': fputs(bigdigit[row][8], stdout); break;
            case '9': fputs(bigdigit[row][9], stdout); break;
        }
    }

    fputc('\n', stdout);
}
```

If you are unfamiliar with `fputs()`, `fputs(stuff, stdout)` is equivalent to `printf("%s", stuff)`.  Similarly, `fputc('\n', stdout)` is equivalent to `printf("\n");`.

In other words, the outer loop is over the rows, and the inner loop is over each big digit to be displayed.  Yes, we do loop ROWS times over the message, but that's okay; we do need to do that.

---

While I too recommend against showing complete solutions, OP's problem was was really just the loop order, so let's make an exception, and look at a complete example program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define  DIGITS  10
#define  ROWS    7

const char *const bigdigit[ROWS][DIGITS] = {
    { " 00 ", " 1", " 22 ", "333 ", "  44 ", "5555", " 666", "7777", " 88 ", " 99 " },
    { "0  0", "11", "2  2", "   3", " 4 4 ", "5   ", "6   ", "   7", "8  8", "9  9" },
    { "0  0", " 1", "   2", "   3", "4  4 ", "5   ", "6   ", "  7 ", "8  8", "9  9" },
    { "0  0", " 1", "  2 ", " 33 ", "44444", "555 ", "666 ", " 7  ", " 88 ", " 999" },
    { "0  0", " 1", " 2  ", "   3", "   4 ", "   5", "6  6", " 7  ", "8  8", "   9" },
    { "0  0", " 1", "2   ", "   3", "   4 ", "5  5", "6  6", " 7  ", "8  8", "   9" },
    { " 00 ", " 1", "2222", "333 ", "   4 ", " 55 ", " 66 ", " 7  ", " 88 ", "999 " }
};

int main(void)
{
    char  message[100];
    int   row, col;

    while (scanf(" %99[0-9]", message) == 1) {

        for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {

            for (col = 0; message[col] != '\0'; col++) {
                fputs(bigdigit[row][message[col] - '0'], stdout);
                fputc(' ', stdout);
            }

            fputc('\n', stdout);
        }

        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `bigdigit` is a two-dimensional array of string literals.  The outer (left) dimension is the row (0 to `ROWS`-1), and the inner (right) dimension is the digit (0 to 9).  This allows us to define the array in nicely human-readable form, as you can see.

The `message` char array is limited to 100 chars, including the end-of-string nul byte, `'\0'`, so the conversion specifier limits the input conversion to 99 characters. The conversion is `[0-9]`, which means a string containing ASCII digits 0 through 9.

The [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) function returns the number of successful conversions. The `scanf(" %99[0-9]", message)` returns 1 if it converts a string consisting of decimal digits, 0 or EOF otherwise.  The space in front of the conversion means that any whitespace (tabs, spaces, newlines) are skipped first.

This example program therefore converts such numbers, one at a time, until no more input is provided, or the input contains something other than a whitespace or a number.  For example, any letter will end the program.

It is important to realize that when any of the `scanf()` family of functions encounters input that it cannot convert as asked, that input will be left in the input buffer. *The un-convertable data is not discarded.* If you wanted to, you'd need to discard that data. (`scanf("%*[\n]");` can be used to discard such data, if the conversion patterns begins with a space. It basically discards the rest of the input line, excluding the newline at end of line.  The `*` means the conversion is skipped; the result is not stored anywhere, and there is no parameter corresponding to that conversion.)

The row loop is the same as explained in the beginning of this answer.

The column loop differs in two features: Instead of looping from `0` to one less than the string length in `message`, the loop is from `0` til the end of the string in `message`. Remember, in C, strings are terminated with a nul character, `'\0'`. (`strlen()` just counts the number of non-nul characters, until it sees a nul character.)

The column loop also prints a space between each digit. This is just so that you do not need to have the letter space in the `bigdigit[][]` array itself.

The "tricky" part in the `bigdigit[row][message[col] - '0']` expression is the `message[col] - '0'` part.  You see, individual characters in strings are really just integers, usually called codes or code points.  In basically all character sets, `0` through `9` have continuous set of codes, so that `message[col] - '0'` evaluates to zero if the col'th character in message[] is a zero digit, one if one digit, and so on, up to nine.

The second `fputc('\n', stdout);` prints an empty line after each big digit string.  That is it for the program.

If you compile the above program, and input `1237 543`, the program will output

```
 1  22  333  7777 
11 2  2    3    7 
 1    2    3   7  
 1   2   33   7   
 1  2      3  7   
 1 2       3  7   
 1 2222 333   7   

5555   44  333  
5     4 4     3 
5    4  4     3 
555  44444  33  
   5    4     3 
5  5    4     3 
 55     4  333
```

Note that in C, standard input is line buffered. (That is, when you type the input, the program actually sees the entire line at once, but only when you press Enter.)  Because the big digit printing is done in a loop that grabs one digit string from the input at a time, the two strings are printed on separate lines.

If you wanted to print the input as it was specified on the line, you'd need to read the entire line (using e.g. `fgets()`), and implement at least the space character (in `bigdigit[][]`, I mean), and change the `fputs(bigdigit[row][message[col] - '0'], stdout)` back to a switch statement so you can output a space. For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define  DIGITS  10
#define  ROWS    7

const char *const bigdigit[ROWS][DIGITS] = {
    { " 00 ", " 1", " 22 ", "333 ", "  44 ", "5555", " 666", "7777", " 88 ", " 99 " },
    { "0  0", "11", "2  2", "   3", " 4 4 ", "5   ", "6   ", "   7", "8  8", "9  9" },
    { "0  0", " 1", "   2", "   3", "4  4 ", "5   ", "6   ", "  7 ", "8  8", "9  9" },
    { "0  0", " 1", "  2 ", " 33 ", "44444", "555 ", "666 ", " 7  ", " 88 ", " 999" },
    { "0  0", " 1", " 2  ", "   3", "   4 ", "   5", "6  6", " 7  ", "8  8", "   9" },
    { "0  0", " 1", "2   ", "   3", "   4 ", "5  5", "6  6", " 7  ", "8  8", "   9" },
    { " 00 ", " 1", "2222", "333 ", "   4 ", " 55 ", " 66 ", " 7  ", " 88 ", "999 " }
};

int main(void)
{
    char  message[100], *line;
    int   row, col;

    while (1) {

        line = fgets(message, sizeof message, stdin);
        if (line == NULL)
            break;

        if (strcspn(line, "\r\n") < 1)
            break;

        for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {

            for (col = 0; line[col] != '\0'; col++) {
                switch (line[col]) {
                case '0': fputs(bigdigit[row][0], stdout); fputc(' ', stdout); break;
                case '1': fputs(bigdigit[row][1], stdout); fputc(' ', stdout); break;
                case '2': fputs(bigdigit[row][2], stdout); fputc(' ', stdout); break;
                case '3': fputs(bigdigit[row][3], stdout); fputc(' ', stdout); break;
                case '4': fputs(bigdigit[row][4], stdout); fputc(' ', stdout); break;
                case '5': fputs(bigdigit[row][5], stdout); fputc(' ', stdout); break;
                case '6': fputs(bigdigit[row][6], stdout); fputc(' ', stdout); break;
                case '7': fputs(bigdigit[row][7], stdout); fputc(' ', stdout); break;
                case '8': fputs(bigdigit[row][8], stdout); fputc(' ', stdout); break;
                case '9': fputs(bigdigit[row][9], stdout); fputc(' ', stdout); break;
                case ' ': fputs("     ", stdout); break;
                }
            }

            fputc('\n', stdout);
        }

        fputc('\n', stdout);

    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you increment `DIGITS`, you can add `bigdigit[row][10]` and so on to the `switch` case, to print e.g. letters and such.

Because space is always just space, instead of using a `bigdigit` entry for it, I just made it five space characters wide, including the inter-letter space.

If you compile and run this program, it will run until you supply it an empty line.  For the same `1237 543` input, this one outputs

```
 1  22  333  7777      5555   44  333  
11 2  2    3    7      5     4 4     3 
 1    2    3   7       5    4  4     3 
 1   2   33   7        555  44444  33  
 1  2      3  7           5    4     3 
 1 2       3  7        5  5    4     3 
 1 2222 333   7         55     4  333
```

There are only two really new things in this program, compared to the previous one: First, instead of `scanf()`, the entire input line is read into `message[]` buffer (limited to one less character in length than the size of `message[]`).  The expression `sizeof message` evaluates to the number of characters in `message` array, including the one reserved for the end-of-string nul character. It only works if `message` is an array, not if it is a pointer.

(If you dynamically allocate memory for `char *message`, then you do need to keep the number of chars you allocated in a separate variable, and supply that to `fgets()`.  There is no standard way of finding out how many characters you have allocated for a pointer afterwards; in C, you must track that yourself if you need it.)

Second change is the funky [`strcspn(line, "\r\n")`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcspn.3.html) function call. It returns the number of characters in `line` up to the end of the string, or up to any of the characters listed (here, carriage return or linefeed, the two characters that are used for newlines in various combinations in different OSes), whichever happens first.

(You sometimes see `line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = '\0';` used to trim off the contents of `line` at the first carriage return or linefeed, removing the newline at end of the string that `fgets()` leaves there.  This is safe as long as `line` is not NULL and contains a string, even if it does not contain a carriage return or a linefeed, because in that case `strcspn()` just returns the length of the string instead.)

The `if (strcspn(line, "\r\n") < 1)` line can be read as *"If there are no characters in `line`, or the first character is a carriage return or a newline, then"*.  I could have written it as `if (line[0] == '\0' || line[0] == '\r' || line[0] == '\n')`, but I thought showing such a nifty little standard function would be appropriate here.

Because there is no `default:` case in the `switch` statement, all other characters except digits and space (and those you add, if you increase `DIGITS` and add their strings to the `bigdigit[][]` array and output as a new `case` statement), are completely ignored.

Comment: All cases could use the same `case '0': fputs(bigdigit[row][message[column] - '0'], stdout);  break;` yet perhaps that is for a later improvement.

Comment: @chux: My thoughts exactly (a good idea for later improvement, I mean). For the same reason, I used `column < columns`, instead of `message[column] != '\0'` as the inner loop condition, avoiding the `strlen()` call.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, ty very much

Comment: @chux, that would be done with someting like the "printf("%s",n[nums[i]-'0'].number);" mencioned before? 
i would need the switch case still?

Comment: @Sawyer: The entire `switch (...) { ... }` block in my example could be replaced with `if (message[column] >= '0' && message[column] <= '9') fputs(bigdigit[row][message[column] - '0'], stdout);`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, it's so optimised, ty very much, now I'm going to stay the rest of the month trying to understand it * -*

Comment: @Sawyer, you might consider using say `char message[25];` and `if (scanf(" %24[0-9]", message) < 1) { fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input!\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`. The `%24[0-9]` is a conversion which says "up to 24 characters of the set `0` through `9`". Because C strings have a terminating nul, `'\0'`, the array must be at least 25 chars long.  (The space in the conversion before it means "skip any whitespace first".) This way you can even omit the `if (message[column] >= '0' && message[column] <= '9')` in the loop, because the `scanf()` only accepts inputs consisting only of digits.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, but then i suppose i would need the strlen func.
what would be more optimised, this or the way with out strlen?

Comment: @Sawyer: Because you had it almost solved by yourself, just had an issue with the loop order, I decided to add two complete example programs you can play with and compare your own implementation against.  Note that these are not intended as "perfect examples", because there is no such thing as perfect. (Me myself, I'd probably use wide character strings, so I could draw the digits nicer, using Unicode-y glyphs.. perhaps even use POSIX.1 `iconv()` to check and choose between representations.) I added them so you and others can explore and compare your own against; to modify and experiment with.

Comment: @NominalAnimal, ty, thats awesome ^-^